# Workfront and Batch Delete of choices

Tags: attask, workfront-api

In reference to this post:

[Workfront and the popt API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47229264/workfront-and-the-popt-api)

What's the appropriate query to delete the choices from a drop-down list? Like a batch delete? I'm working on something where I have records in there now that I need to delete, and I keep getting errors because there are already values in WorkFront that match. For instance, my queryString has "+" in it, and I'm working on getting them taken out, but it gives me an error. I just need to be able to delete the entries so I can "start over".

Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm very new to WorkFront, and their documentation when it comes to these things seems to be rather sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deletion doesn't support batch objects (it's a 1:1 call:action) so you'll have to get a list of all the UUIDs that you want to delete and then call a delete function on each of them.

```
foreach($popt_UUID in $listOfPOPTs){
{    
  DELETE https://<url>.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v7.0/POPT/<$popt_UUID>?apiKey=<key>
}
```

You'll get a response from each of them so you may want to pipe the output to a null device.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, Brian! I'll give that a shot and report back!